# Error when saving multiple figures to a one multi-page PDF document

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, pdfpages

I'm trying to save several figures to one multi-page PDF document.  My code is as follows:

```
import matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf
pdf = matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf.PdfPages('output.pdf')

sns.set_style('darkgrid')

g = sns.factorplot(data=df,
                   x='Date',
                   y='Product_Count',
                   col='Company',
                   col_wrap=4,
                   sharey=False)
g.set_xlabels('')
g.set_ylabels('product count')
g.set_xticklabels(rotation=45)
plt.locator_params(axis = 'x', nbins = 8)

f = sns.factorplot(data=df,
                   x='Date',
                   y='Volume_Count',
                   col='Company',
                   col_wrap=4,
                   sharey=False)
f.set_xlabels('')
f.set_ylabels('volume count')
f.set_xticklabels(rotation=45)
plt.locator_params(axis = 'x', nbins = 8)

figures = [g, f]

for figure in figures:
    pdf.savefig(figure)
pdf.close()
```

I'm seeing this error message:

```
ValueError: No such figure: <seaborn.axisgrid.FacetGrid object at 0x237CD5F0>
```

Is there something wrong with the iteration?

Comment: You need to dig the `matplotlib.figure.Figure` object out of the seaborn objects.

Comment: @tcaswell - are you saying that I need to **delete** `plt.locator_params(axis = 'x', nbins = 8)`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`g` and `f` are not [`matplotlib.figure.Figure`](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure) objects, they are [`seaborn.axisgrid.FacetGrid`](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html) objects (as mentioned by [@tcaswell in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39400135/error-when-saving-multiple-figures-to-a-one-multi-page-pdf-document-python-sea/39408904#comment66127098_39400135)).

`PdfPages` needs the `Figure` instances, and luckily they are easy to extract from the `FacetGrid` objects, using `g.fig` and `f.fig`.

So, all you need to do is change one line, from

```
figures = [g, f]
```

to:

```
figures = [g.fig, f.fig]
```